# XUbuntu: Make Shift+NumPad work like Windows

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, xfce, numpad

Ok, I've used Ubuntu with GNOME for a while, but now I'm using XUbuntu. In Ubuntu, there used to be a keyboard preference which makes the numpad more sane, it was called something like "Make Shift+NumPad work like Windows".

The problem this options solves is, that when you press NumPad 7, it acts like the "Home" key, which is all fine, but if you press Shift+NumPad 7, it acts like the "7" key, which is not fine because I'm on a laptop and the regular "Home" key requires me to pull of an anatomically insane move. Anyways, this option made Shift+NumPad 7 act like the "Home" key.

I can't find that option under XUbuntu. How do I set it?

*Update:* GUI or command line, doesn't matter.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

After some grepping I found the solution: You need to add the `numpad:microsoft` option to the XkbOptions. On older Ubuntus, do that in your xorg.conf. On newer ones open the file `/etc/default/keyboard` and change this line:

```
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

to

```
XKBOPTIONS="numpad:microsoft"
```

Save and reboot (restarting X doesn't seem to work, at least not with RAlt+PrintScreen+K). You may need to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` for changes to take effect.

Comment: Can you adapt this answer for a non-root user?

Comment: Just used this successfully on Ubuntu 15.10. Thanks!

Comment: @einpoklum - you need root.

Comment: No need to reboot (on 16.04). Just need to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.

Comment: The reboot wasn't required for me. Otherwise, great answer.

Comment: Yes! This has driven me crazy for so long. Reboot no longer required (hey, the original answer was 2011, it's amazing it's still correct!)

Comment: It worked for me (Ubuntu 18.10), reboot was required.

Comment: It worked for me (Xubuntu 20.04), reboot was required

Comment: Works like a charm on Ubuntu 20.04 without rebooting and without restarting any applications. I specifically use `shift+7` for `home` and `shift+1` for `end`.

Answer (score 21):

Ubuntu 14.04 have no more "Miscellaneous compatibility options" in the keyboard settings. Editing `/etc/default/keyboard` also is not a working solution. But dconf database contains the required options with key `/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options`. This options should be completed with `numpad:microsoft` to something like `['grp:alt_shift_toggle', 'grp_led:scroll', 'numpad:microsoft']` manually in dconf-editor or using  this script:

```
# !/bin/bash
old=`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`
new=`echo $old | sed "s/'numpad:microsoft'//g" | sed -r "s/(, )+/, /g" | sed -r "s/(, )?]/, 'numpad:microsoft']/"`
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "$new"
```

Comment: awesome!! what on earth was someone smoking to remove this...

        Or, if this feature is some "evil windows thing", how are you supposed to do shift-end on the laptop, when the regular key is in a hard to reach place?

Comment: Great answer ! Btw instead of using the command line you can also install the dconf-editor in Ubuntu >= 12.04

Check this answer for more details http://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-what-is-its-function-and-how-do-i-use-it

Comment: Works like a charm in 16.10. dconf-editor helped too, thanks @Storm!

Comment: On Elementary OS Loki, this is the only option that seems to work.

Answer (score 19):

In Xubuntu 16.04 the XKBOPTIONS setting ( XKBOPTIONS="numpad:microsoft" ) in /etc/default/keyboard is ignored - I consider this to be a bug.

I'm using the following command as workaround:
     **`setxkbmap -option 'numpad:microsoft'`**

In order to run the above command automatically when starting the graphical
desktop environment, I've create an Application Autostart entry:
*Menu > Settings > Session and Startup > Application Autostart > Add*

> Name: Make Shift+NumPad work like MS Windows
>   Description: *whatsoever*
>      Command:**`setxkbmap -option 'numpad:microsoft'`**

Comment: Works great, and without restart, thanks! But what do you mean by "Menu > Settings"? From where? I don't think you mean system settings.

Comment: Hi David. I have created 5 screenshots: (1/5) https://imgur.com/a/h00IQ | (2/5) https://imgur.com/a/xUcJS | (3/5) https://imgur.com/a/n9Pq3 | (4/5) https://imgur.com/a/0m8Df | (5/5) https://imgur.com/a/rMVdj - hope this helps ;-) .

Comment: This works on XUbuntu 18.04. No restart needed

Comment: Confirmed it works in 19 as well. The auto start is not here though. Just add a .sh to /etc/init.d

Comment: Works for Ubuntu Budgie 20.04! :+1:

Comment: @F.M. For some reason doesn't work in Ubuntu 21.10. Maybe you have the understanding?

Answer (score 14):

Glad I found your post. Using Natty Narwhal, I found a similar option in the Keyboard settings.

1. Search for Keyboard
2. Click Layouts tab
3. Click Options button
4. Expand miscellaneous compatibility options
5. Check "Shift with numeric keypad keys works as in MS Windows"
6. Close and you're good!

Comment: Thank you! This is the only solution that worked for me - editing `/etc/default/keyboard` didn't work.

Comment: That option has been removed in 13.10. It can still be selected by installing gnome-tweak-tool: `sudo apt-get install gnome-link-tool`. Then you'll find it under "Typing" in the "Miscellaneous compatibility options" list.

Comment: @f.cipriani I don't know if that was a typo in your comment or if the tool has been renamed, but the current correct name is `gnome-tweak-tool`.

Comment: Thanks @waldir, that was a typo, it is actually `gnome-tweak-tool`

Comment: In Linux Mint 18 (Cinnamon), it appears the desired option under "Miscellaneous compatibility options" is "Numlock on: digits, Shift switches to arrow keys, Numlock off: always arrow keys (as in MS Windows)".

Answer (score 6):

For uBuntu 18.04, another options is to use Dconf-Editor, a powerful GUI for most uBuntu settings. If not installed, open Terminal and type:

- `apt-get update`
- `apt-get install dconf-editor -y`

Open `dconf Editor`, then `/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options`.

On a fresh uBuntu installation, `Custom value` will be blank. Turn `Use default value` OFF then:

- insert `['numpad:microsoft']` (if blank) or
- append `, 'numpad:microsoft'` (after whatever is there, if not blank)

For example, `['caps:none', 'numpad:microsoft']` which both disables Caps Lock and uses the NumPad as in Windows. Close `dconf Editor`, no reboot required.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem on lubuntu.  I tried changing the `/etc/default/keyboard` file, but it didn't help.

I think the reason might be that I had Layout changer on my system.  However, adding `numpad:microsoft` in the "Advanced setxkbmap Options" field in the options of the Keyboard Layout Handler actually worked.  I didn't even have to reboot the X.

Comment: It means run this command: `setxkbmap -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll,numpad:microsoft"`

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 19.10, you can get this functionality by installing `gnome-tweak-tool`, then opening it, going to `Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options` then expanding `Miscellaneous compatibility options` and checking `Num Lock on: digits; Shift for arrow keys, Num Lock off: arrow keys (as in Windows)`, as shown here:

[image: Gnome Tweak Tool Config]

The changes take effect immediately.  It seems to change the same setting as the answer by @AlainD

Answer (score 1):

Kubuntu 20.04 also has `Miscellaneous compatibility options` menu! So, you can fix numlock and shift+home / shift+end issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Running Ubuntu 20.04 in Virtual Box on a Windows host, I needed to turn on these options in Tweaks to get shift- and control-shift- keys to work in Windows style.

- Tweaks > Keyboard & Mouse > Additional Layout Options > Miscellaneous compatibility options > Shift does not cancel Num Lock, chooses 3rd level instead
- Tweaks > Keyboard & Mouse > Additional Layout Options > Layout of Numeric Keypad > Wang 724 keypad with unicode additions (arrows and math operators; math operators on default level)

For example, in a text editor with NumLock on, this allows ctrl-shift-numpad4 to move left to the start of a word while selecting the word.

Answer (score -1):

For me 'keypad:pointerkeys' option helped on Lubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver

Comment: I frequent many sites in stackexchange.com and I think I have noticed a disturbing pattern: the sites with the highest percentage of unhelpful answers seem to be the linux sites.