# Xubuntu - how to disable SHIFT toggles numpad keys?

Tags: 12.10, shortcut-keys, keyboard, xubuntu, xfce

By default In Ubuntu I can perform <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> to select content from caret to start of string, while <kbd>NumLock</kbd> is turned off. But if in that case I press just <kbd>Home</kbd>, it will type 1 instead of moving caret to start of string, and this is expected behavior considering that <kbd>NumLock</kbd> is off. To use <kbd>Home</kbd> I will need to turn on <kbd>NumLock</kbd>.

So - how can I change it to Microsoft-defaults, when perform <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Home</kbd> doesnt need changing state of <kbd>NumLock</kbd>?

Ive already discovered this q:
[XUbuntu: Make Shift+NumPad work like Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57079/xubuntu-make-shiftnumpad-work-like-windows)

But it does not help. My `/etc/default/keyboard` file looks now:

```
# Check /usr/share/doc/keyboard-configuration/README.Debian for
# documentation on what to do after having modified this file.
# The following variables describe your keyboard and can have the same
# values as the XkbModel, XkbLayout, XkbVariant and XkbOptions options
# in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="numpad:microsoft"

# If you don't want to use the XKB layout on the console, you can
# specify an alternative keymap.  Make sure it will be accessible
# before /usr is mounted.
# KMAP=/etc/console-setup/defkeymap.kmap.gz
```

UPD
Also I found that on login screen <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> works properly!