# Make Ubuntu 14.04 NumPad behave like Windows

Tags: 14.04, windows, keyboard, numlock, numpad

I'm using an external keyboard with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and dual-booting Windows 8.1, although that may be irrelevant to the question.

With the NumLock switched on, I can type numbers by default and I can access the home/end, page up/down & arrow buttons by pressing Shift key as well.

With the NumLock switched off, I can access the home/end, page up/down and arrow buttons by default while pressing Shift allows me to select the number keys.

However, on Windows, the Home/End buttons function as Home/End buttons regardless of NumLock state. In other words, pressing Shift and Home/End will always result in Home/End button presses which is useful when typing, editing and jumping around large chunks of text.

The only answer I found which is still relevant to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57079/xubuntu-make-shiftnumpad-work-like-windows/500941#500941) but the main problem is that I'm not entirely sure how to implement that script. Or really, how to use that code at all. Hence, I would really appreciate an explanation of how to actually use that code or, even better for me, a graphical way to achieve the same result.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

That answer worked perfectly for me, you just need to create file (let's say `keyboard.sh`) in your `home` directory, copy/paste that code into this file, then give it execution rights (`chmod +x keyboard.sh` in terminal) and execute it.
You can delete that file after execution.