# Ubuntu 16.04.2 when pressing END key - text gets selected instead of going to end of the line

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, asus, numpad

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 on my laptop: Asus Zenbook Pro UX501VW.

In my laptop's keyboard the <kbd>End</kbd> key is located in the numpad alongside the key <kbd>1</kbd>.

In Windows, when I want to go to end of line I need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> (NumLock should be turned on).

I noticed that in Ubuntu when I am pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> it goes to the end of the line BUT it also selects all the text from the current position of the cursor to the end.

How can I fix it so it only goes to end of the line without selecting text? (like Windows)

I already tried to do this:

[XUbuntu: Make Shift+NumPad work like Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57079/xubuntu-make-shiftnumpad-work-like-windows)

And it didn't work.

Please help me :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can view edit and reassign the keyboard keys with GSettings, bellow is a link to the manual page for details.

gsettings - GSettings configuration tool
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/gsettings.1.html

Comment: Can you please explain me how to configure and use GSettings in my particular problem?