# Shift+home and shift+end don't work in laptop

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, laptop, numlock

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and these key combinations do not work. If I toggle <kbd>NumLock</kbd> then <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> without <kbd>Shift</kbd> don't work properly. I found some proposed solutions for older versions of Ubuntu but they refer to menu settings that no longer seem to exist.

Comment: If Home and End are sharing your numeric keypad this is by design. If not, it's odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't have enough reputation to mark as duplicate, but copy pasting from [this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44921/how-to-change-shift-keypad-key-behavior):

> - Open "keyboard preferences" ; in the "Layouts" tab, click the "Options..." button
> - Look for the "Miscellaneous compatibility options" group
> - Select the "Shift with numeric keypad keys work as in MS Windows" checkbox.

Comment: That does not exist in 14.04, but you lead me to [a working solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/500941/86775).