# How to deactivate shift+numpad=number? Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: keyboard, laptop, numpad

Hllo er1. I'm quite new whit Ubuntu, actually with whole Linux.
I've gor a laptop without PageUp,PageDown, Home, End keys. Indeed, I need to deactivate the numpad almost everytime and activate it only when I want to write long numbers. Even, I got used to move with the numpad arrows.

Often, I need to select much code or text and ned to press Shit+PageDown or Shift+Arrow (in numpad). But, I end up writing numbers everywhere!

Everythig I want is to deactivate this Shift function. It is driving me mad.

Answer (score 4):

Terminal:

```
setxkbmap -option 'numpad:microsoft'
```

And voila!

Here is the answer: [How to change Shift + <Keypad Key> behavior?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44921/how-to-change-shift-keypad-key-behavior)

Comment: Work on Ubuntu 20.10 also

Comment: Work on Zorin OS